# Wrong number of arguments on initialize

Tags: ruby

In my `Triangle` class below, I have an `initialize` method that takes three arguments.

```
class Triangle
    attr_accessor :side1, :side2, :side3

    def initalize(one, two, three)
        @side1 = one
        @side2 = two
        @side3 = three
    end
end
```

When I create a new class and initialize it with three arguments,

```
one = Triangle.new(1,2,3)
puts one.side1
puts one.side2
puts one.side3
```

I get this error:

```
"lib/triangle.rb:21:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 0) (ArgumentError)".
```

What's up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
def initalize # typo
def initialize # correct
```

BTW, a less manual way of handling the scenario in `kind` is:

```
def kind
  :scalene if [@side1, @side2, @side3].uniq.length == 3
end
```

Comment: @coreyward, if you don't mind me asking, what exactly is `:scalene` here `def kind` method? I just googled it thinking it was a ruby method and it's not? A tad confused on what it is here ... in math-wise, it means 3 unequal sides ... but it's made-up method here?

Comment: @user27307254534534534543675765 See the original question. It's a method on `Triangle`; the method, as should be apparent if you know Ruby, returns a symbol `:scalene` if the object meets the conditions stated.

Comment: @user27307254534534534543675765 The code it belonged to was edited out by a user/moderator.